# Calculating a limit with integral inside

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

The task is to find the following limit:
$$\lim_{\lambda \to 0+} \frac{1}{\ln \lambda}\int_{\lambda}^{a}\frac{\cos{x}}{x}dx$$

I couldn't verify my answer using Wolfram Alpha (btw, maybe you know how to construct a proper query for it?) so I ask here.

$\textbf{Solution}$

1. We have the uncertainty of $\frac{\infty}{-\infty} = -\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ so we can use the L'Hospital's rule. Let's find the derivatives:

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\int_{\lambda}^{a}\frac{\cos{x}}{x}dx = \frac{d}{d\lambda}[F(a) - F(\lambda)] = -f(\lambda) = -\frac{\cos\lambda}{\lambda}$$

$$\frac{d}{d\lambda}\ln\lambda = \frac{1}{\lambda}$$

2. Now, use the L'Hospital's rule:

$$\lim_{\lambda \to 0+} \frac{1}{\ln \lambda}\int_{\lambda}^{a}\frac{\cos{x}}{x}dx = \lim_{\lambda \to 0+} \frac{-\frac{cos(\lambda)}{\lambda}}{\frac{1}{\lambda}} = \lim_{\lambda \to 0+} (-\cos \lambda) = -1$$

I took this task from some college olympiad and it feels to me alarming that my solution is so easy.

Comment: Good you can also plot a graph for this and then take the limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, provided by me seems valid, but authors gave another one.

First, they split the numerator into two terms:
$$\int_\lambda^a \frac{\cos{x}}{x}dx = \int_\lambda^a\frac{1 + \cos{x} - 1}{x}dx = \int_\lambda^a \frac{1}{x}dx + \int_\lambda^a \frac{\cos{x} - 1}{x}dx$$

And now they considered each of these two limits separately:

$$\frac{1}{\ln{\lambda}}\int_\lambda^a\frac{1}{x}dx = \frac{1}{\ln{\lambda}}(\ln{a} - \ln{\lambda}) \to -1$$

And second term is less then some constant $C$. Note, that $\frac{\cos{x} - 1}{x}$ is continuous at $0$ and negative on $[0, \infty$). So:
$$\Big|\int_\lambda^a \frac{\cos{x} - 1}{x} \Big| \leq \Big|\int_0^a \frac{\cos{x} - 1}{x} \Big| = C$$
So $\frac{C}{\ln{\lambda}} \to 0$.